# Jar communication with the project local file

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar

So I have Spring boot project in which I am trying to use Velocity templates. The stuff related to Velocity template is being added as jar.

Here is my project structure:

```
 java-> esub -> db -> persistence-> Group.java
              -> domain -> (many domain files)
     -> org.iowa.rec -> many packages
```

So I am invoking my code from jar something like this:

```
     RecordedMessage message = new RecordedMessage (PropertyLoader.getInstance());
    message.sendMessage(userProfileDO, group);
```

The "group" I am passing is local to my project. When I try to run my app it complains for :

```
    java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "esub/db/persistence/Group"
```

I get no errors at compile time but only gets at Runtime.  So I am guessing it's unable to reach out to that particular folder.

I have tried provided scope for jar but then it leads me to complain about more files.

Jar structure :

```
  sub -> *.vm(all vm files)
      -> esub -> mail -> (some java files)
```

Answer (score 0):

On further research I found out that this is a case of cyclic dependency. Before creating that jar, we need to have the classes from below as a dependency :

```
  java-> esub -> db -> persistence-> Group.java
          -> domain -> (many domain files)
```

And then once the jar we create after the dependency we can use into the TestProject by adding it as a dependency and then it won't complain for the file. This will be cyclic dependency and highly discouraged.